# How do you update the default route Visual Studio generates when you hit F5 on an MVC view?

Tags: visual-studio, model-view-controller

I recently reorganized my views in my folder structure. Initially, I had a folder for each view, and each folder just had one item - the view.cshtml file. This was messy, so I created three categorical folders and moved all the views into the appropriate categories.

I was able to fix the ActionLink-based routing by updating `return View()` to the format `return View("/Views/CategoryFolderName/ViewName.cshtml")`. Keep in mind that when actually I navigate to this page, the URL in the browser is `localhost:12345/ControllerName/ActionName`.

My problem is this:

If I want to edit a page - we'll call it ImportantView, I'll open up ImportantView.csthml. I'll edit it, and then I'll hit F5 to see the results. When I do this, it *tries* to take me to `localhost:12345/CategoryFolderName/ImportantView` and gives me a "resource not found" error. What I WANT it to do is to take me to `localhost:12345/ImportantViewController/ImportantViewAction`.

Is it possible to fix my solution such that I can retain my folder organization and cleanliness, F5 will take me to the correct page, and actionlinks will still route to the correct location?

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't work that way. Just like hitting F5 in a shared view it will open up the same 404 page. I think not even the right-click Go to Controller would work in your case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're correct. I figured there might be some place where the default routing is stored, and I hoped I'd be able to just hand-jam some fixes, but maybe not. I can probably just revert my move and use Areas, but that's kind of a pain. Oh well. Thanks anyways!

Comment: But you're not using the controller name as part of the view path so I doubt it would work even with areas

Comment: Well my idea was to revert everything to the original way of doing things, then just put my mess of folders into areas. They'd be properly linked and messy, but the messiness would be contained, if that makes any sense. I was just hoping for a better solution than that.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean, if you're using areas as your categories it still wouldn't take you to the correct URL when you try to debug right?